# PHP Get only directory path

Tags: php, path, directory

I have:

```
$page_file_temp = $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];
```

which will output: `/templates/somename/index.php`

I want to extract from that path only `"/templates/somename/"`

How can I do it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 34, accepted):

```
$page_directory = dirname($page_file_temp);
```

See [dirname](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php).

Comment: NOTE that dirname() is simplistic - it does not examine the filesystem.  For example dirname('/folder1/folder2/folder3/') would return '/folder1/folder2'.  i.e it assumes that folder3 is not a directory.

Answer (score 10):

Maybe this is your solution:

```
$rootPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
$thisPath = dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
$onlyPath = str_replace($rootPath, '', $thisPath);
```

For example:

`$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` is the server's root-path like this `/home/abc/domains/abc.com/public_html`

`$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` is about the whole path to that script like this `/home/abc/domains/abc.com/public_html/uploads/home/process.php`

Then we can have:

`$rootPath` like this `/home/abc/domains/abc.com/public_html`

`$thisPath` like this `/home/abc/domains/abc.com/public_html/uploads/home`

And `$onlyPath` like this `/uploads/home`

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [dirname()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php) function.

From the documents, `dirname()` removes the trailing slash. If you want to keep it you can append the constant DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR to the result.

```
$dir = dirname('mystring/and/path.txt').DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) will account for GET variables and "fragments" (portion of URL after #) amongst other URL-specific parts.

```
$url = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; // OR $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']

echo parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative:

`$directory = pathinfo($page_file_temp,PATHINFO_DIRNAME);`

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php

Comment: This is no different from: $directory = dirname($page_file_temp);  Both are problematic in that they're simplistic: they always strip the last segment - even if it's a directory!